# Sync Framework Insert Triggers With Yii2 not working

Tags: php, sql-server, yii, yii2, microsoft-sync-framework

I have used **Sql Server** with **PHP** framework to Sync online database with local database. I made an application in .net Framework and used **Microsoft SyncFramework** to sync two databases. The problem I am facing now is that whenever database is provisioned and tracking tables are made along with triggers and stored procedures. All create functionality stops working in the PHP app. I have used the following condition in YII to save a few more thing in YII framework application.

```
if ($loaded && $model->save()) {
}
```

`$model->save()` always returns false and do not return any error. On the other hand when I try to insert record in the database using .Net entity framework it returns true. So my Guess at this time is that there is some thing that has a conflict with `$model->save()` of YII and sql insert trigger  made by **Sync Framework**.

Any pointers to solve this problem will be appreciated.

***Note*** The problem only occurs with insert trigger. Update and delete trigger works fine. Secondly even in insert trigger, records are inserted in Database

**Stored Procedure**

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[branch_bulkinsert]    Script Date: 08/19/2017 3:56:13 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[branch_bulkinsert]
    @sync_min_timestamp BigInt,
    @sync_scope_local_id Int,
    @changeTable [branch_BulkType] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
-- use a temp table to store the list of PKs that successfully got updated/inserted
DECLARE @changed TABLE ([ID] varchar(64), PRIMARY KEY ([ID]));

-- update/insert into the base table
MERGE [branch] AS base USING
-- join done here against the side table to get the local timestamp for concurrency check
(SELECT p.*, t.local_update_peer_timestamp FROM @changeTable p LEFT JOIN [branch_tracking] t ON p.[ID] = t.[ID]) AS changes ON changes.[ID] = base.[ID]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND changes.local_update_peer_timestamp <= @sync_min_timestamp OR changes.local_update_peer_timestamp IS NULL THEN
INSERT ([ID], [sr], [branch_code], [branch_name], [created_by], [address], [is_deleted], [approved], [created_on], [application_ID]) VALUES (changes.[ID], changes.[sr], changes.[branch_code], changes.[branch_name], changes.[created_by], changes.[address], changes.[is_deleted], changes.[approved], changes.[created_on], changes.[application_ID])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[ID] INTO @changed; -- populates the temp table with successful PKs

UPDATE side SET
update_scope_local_id = @sync_scope_local_id, 
scope_update_peer_key = changes.sync_update_peer_key, 
scope_update_peer_timestamp = changes.sync_update_peer_timestamp,
local_update_peer_key = 0,
create_scope_local_id = @sync_scope_local_id,
scope_create_peer_key = changes.sync_create_peer_key,
scope_create_peer_timestamp = changes.sync_create_peer_timestamp,
local_create_peer_key = 0
FROM 
[branch_tracking] side JOIN 
(SELECT p.[ID], p.sync_update_peer_timestamp, p.sync_update_peer_key, p.sync_create_peer_key, p.sync_create_peer_timestamp FROM @changed t JOIN @changeTable p ON p.[ID] = t.[ID]) AS changes ON changes.[ID] = side.[ID]
SELECT [ID] FROM @changeTable t WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT [ID] from @changed i WHERE t.[ID] = i.[ID])
END
GO
```

**Insert Trigger**

```
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[branch_insert_trigger]    Script Date: 08/19/2017 3:52:43 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[branch_insert_trigger] ON [dbo].[branch] FOR INSERT AS
UPDATE [side] SET [sync_row_is_tombstone] = 0, [local_update_peer_key] = 0, [restore_timestamp] = NULL, [update_scope_local_id] = NULL, [last_change_datetime] = GETDATE() FROM [branch_tracking] [side] JOIN INSERTED AS [i] ON [side].[ID] = [i].[ID]
INSERT INTO [branch_tracking] ([i].[ID], [create_scope_local_id], [local_create_peer_key], [local_create_peer_timestamp], [update_scope_local_id], [local_update_peer_key], [sync_row_is_tombstone], [last_change_datetime], [restore_timestamp]) SELECT [i].[ID], NULL, 0, @@DBTS+1, NULL, 0, 0, GETDATE() , NULL FROM INSERTED AS [i] LEFT JOIN [branch_tracking] [side] ON [side].[ID] = [i].[ID] WHERE [side].[ID] IS NULL
```